# python script slowing the data load to a database

Tags: python, memory-optimization

hi I am trying to load data to a database (mysql and sqlserver) using insert sql scripts in python
cur.execute(query,(data list))
, after inserting 100 mb volume of data the loading process is slowing down each record 7 min approximatley after 100mb data . am running the python code in linux redhat 8 .how can i optimise this so that it runs the same as first 100 mb data

env : linux
ram : 8 gb
instance type : t2 medium
python 3.8

Comment: Additional information request. Complete t2 name, please.
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.